# Difference between Asp.Net Core 1.0 and .Net Core 1.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

First of all sorry for my weak English. I have nearly **no idea** about the differences between **asp.net**, **asp.net core** and **.net core**, etc. I have searched in google about what they are for nearly a whole day. As I have learned, Asp.Net 5 has changed its name to Asp.Net Core 1.0. Also, there is a new framework, .NET Core 1.0, provided to develop cross-platform applications.

Now I have some questions, hopefully not meaningless.

I want to learn the difference between **Asp.Net Core 1.0** and **.Net Core 1.0**. If I want to develop a project, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Lastly if I want to use one of them for a **cross-platform application** which one is preferable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there's no .NET Core 2.0 yet. .You should ignore the RC versions, which are release candidates - the full 1.0 versions of both have just been released. Basically, .NET Core is a portable execution environment, and ASP.NET Core is a web serving platform built on top of that. If you're building a web app, you want ASP.NET Core. If you're not, you don't...

Comment: There are clearly blog posts and images to demonstrate the relationship, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx. If you find it difficult to understand such English posts, then the task should be learning it first, or find an expert in your region and see if he/she can translate them well.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, your answer also cleared my mind. I want to ask another question about .net core. If I want to develop an android app using .net core 1.0, do I have to use Xamarin or is there another choice?

Comment: At the moment, you have to use Xamarin as far as I'm aware - which I don't *believe* is .NET Core yet, although I'd expect it to be at some point.

Comment: At the moment, you have to use Xamarin as far as I'm aware - which I don't *believe* is .NET Core yet, although I'd expect it to be at some point.

Comment: Alright thanks again

Comment: @JonSkeet may I ask one more question? I am still reading about this topic because I have to prepare a report. Is Asp.Net Core 1.0 on .Net Framework or on .Net Core? And is it cross-platform?

Comment: It can be on either. If it only depends on .NET Core, then it's portable, yes.

Comment: Sorry,I don't get it, how can it be on either? If it depends on .NET Core then what difference left between .Net Core 1.0.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.Net is for web development specifically, .Net is the general framework behind it. So if you're building a web site, REST API, etc. you'd use ASP.Net, otherwise just .Net.

And [.Net Core 1.0 released a couple days ago](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETCore10IsNowReleased.aspx) so don't bother with the RC2 version (release candidate).

Your link to 2.0 is to some random Nuget package with a 2.0 version,  nothing to do with .Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

**.NET Core 1.0** is not the next version of .NET 4.6.2 (Full .NET Framework).
If it is the next version it should have more features than the previous version. But according to Microsoft .NET Core 1.0 doesn't have some of the features .NET 4.6 got. That's why they named it as .NET Core 1.0 instead of .NET 5.

In ASP.NET Core 1.0 they are using .NET Core 1.0 as [reference](https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0-rc1/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html). That means we don't need to install .NET framework to run our ASP.NET Core 1.0 application.

If you are going to develop cross platform web application you have to use ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

**.NET Core** is a Framework for building cross-platform applications using C# or other .NET tools. It builds upon .NET.

**ASP.NET Core** is basically when you use .NET Core in order to create Web applications. Technically, it's made of .NET Core libraries.

If you want to know more about why and when ASP.NET Core can be used, you can read more for free from my book here: https://leanpub.com/netcore/read_sample (select the *Why ASP.NET Core ?* chapter).

Answer (score -2):

.Net Core 1.0 is the new name for the latest version of the .Net Framework. It has been re-written from the ground up.

ASP.Net Core 1.0 is essentially the new version of ASP.Net MVC and Web.API  combined in to a single product that leverages the new .Net Core 1.0. Like .Net Core 1.0, ASP.Net Core 1.0 has also been rewritten from the ground up.

Both products .Net Core 1.0 and ASP.Net Core 1.0 have been given full release status within the last few weeks.

The .Net Core 2.0 link you posted is actually for .Net Core 1.0 but the package is version 2.0.7