# What are the differences between asp.net, asp.net mvc and asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I know what is the difference between ASP.Net (webforms) and ASP.Net MVC but it seems that a new technology called asp.net core is coming out.
Do you know if it is a new concept or if this mean the kernel of asp.net, common to asp.net and asp.net mvc ?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.asp.net/learn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between ASP.NET 5, .NET Core, and ASP.NET Core 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820947/whats-the-difference-between-asp-net-5-net-core-and-asp-net-core-5)

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net has been rewritten from scratch to be modular, cloud ready, and much more performing.
There is .Net Core, Asp.net Core and some frameworks like EntityFramework Core.

It is the same technology, same concept, same classes, just the core is different with some few differences that can be migrated easily.

asp.net core can now run on windows, linux and MAC