# How to use LDAP in ASP.NET Boilerplate (Free Startup Template)

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I would like to integrate authentication via Active Directory in my .net Core app using Free Startup Template version of the Boilerplate. I followed the instruction in the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management) such as installing `Abp.Zero.Ldap` package, creating `LdapAuthenticationSource` class, and injecting dependency like:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroLdapModule))]
public class MyApplicationCoreModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof (MyLdapAuthenticationSource));    
    }

    ...
}
```

Do I need to define any custom settings by using a class implementing `ILdapSettings` interface? Or create any class or files referencing to [this folder](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-forsaken/tree/master/src/Abp.Zero.Ldap/Ldap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## .NET Core 2.0

The instructions may not work, as LDAP / AD auth extension for .NET Core isn't implemented yet.

Track this feature: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2755

## .NET Framework 4.6.1

By installing `Abp.Zero.Ldap` package, you're already referencing that module (moved [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/tree/b4b78071d8fdcadf91ee83b51a8868ae57408845/src/Abp.Zero.Ldap/Ldap)).

As mentioned in [LDAP/Active Directory > Settings](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#settings):

> LdapAuthenticationSource expects **ILdapSettings** as a constructor argument. This interface is used to get LDAP settings like domain, user name and password to connect to Active Directory. Default implementation (**LdapSettings** class) gets these settings from the setting manager.
>
> If you work with Setting manager, then no problem. You can change LDAP settings using [setting manager API](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management). If you want, you can add an initial/seed data to database to enable LDAP auth by default.

So, you don't need to create a class that implements `ILdapSettings`. The benefit of using the Setting Manager is that it stores the settings in your database. A custom class is for getting it from elsewhere or hardcoding it (useful if you just want to try, but a big no-no in production / git commit).

For a start, you can add seed data for your Host in [DefaultSettingsCreator](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/Seed/Host/DefaultSettingsCreator.cs#L26) with [LdapSettingNames](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/bc266e3503fcb2825684ec829cc356815f94f397/src/Abp.Zero.Ldap/Ldap/Configuration/LdapSettingNames.cs):

```
public void Create()
{
    // ...

    // LDAP
    AddSettingIfNotExists(LdapSettingNames.IsEnabled, "false");
    // AddSettingIfNotExists(LdapSettingNames...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I used a Core 2.0 template with a Full .NET Framework for Target framework. Dunno what that means but there is no longer reference error during dependency injection which I got when using the Core 2.0 template with .NET Core (Cross-Platform) for Target Framework.

Comment: Yes, see [ASP.NET Core vs .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136118/net-core-vs-asp-net-core).

Comment: Thanks! i'll give it a shot!

Comment: Is this solved? I got it working but how can I validate my user on AD without passing its password ? thanks