# Integration of LDAP in ABP

Tags: ldap, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to use a combination of LDAP and Windows Authentication for authenticating the user but not quite sure how to implement it. I have already gone through the [External Authentication](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication) and have implemented `MyExternalAuthSource` as per the document describes and it works fine but not fully addressed my needs! With that sample, I still need to send the username and password from the login web page whereas what I actually want is having the user authenticated automatically by the system into the app.

Here are some questions that I have got:

1. Can I test the LDAP function on my local PC which is not on a
   domain?
2. By installing the `Abp.Zero.Ldap` into the application, do I still need to have my own `MyExternalAuthSource` class that implements the `DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource`?
3. Are there any changes needed from the Client side (angular in my case), for example modifying the login page or implement the hack that was mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820965/integrated-windows-authentication-in-abp-framework) with passing a dummy username and password?
4. I can't see where I should use the `windowsIdentity.IsAuthenticated` to check if the user is authenticated. Do I really need to do it at all?
5. The `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated` is always true regardless the value set in for the `windowsAuthentication`.

Comment: Add `[DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroLdapModule))]` to your module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LDAP in ASP.NET Boilerplate (Free Startup Template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628282/how-to-use-ldap-in-asp-net-boilerplate-free-startup-template)

Comment: yeah that works with that and has left me with anther bunch of questions!

Comment: @aaron any assist you possibly can give me in above questions?