# How can I combine windows login and anonymous authentication by using AD in asp.net boilerplate (.net mvc)? IIS HTTP Error 404.15

Tags: asp.net, ldap, asp.net-boilerplate

I have followed the instructions like the guide said：
[LDAP/Active Directory](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#ldap-active-directory)
and [How to use LDAP in ASP.NET Boilerplate (Free Startup Template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628282/how-to-use-ldap-in-asp-net-boilerplate-free-startup-template)

But with no success.

Below is my trial and error:

User Scenario:

- Most of the users are from the domain, so those domain users should not see the login page and should be able to auto login the platform.
- Some of the users are not domain users, for those who have access to the platform but not belong to the domain should pop out the login page and input username/password to login.

Here is a snap of my authentication code:

```
If(!HttpConetxt.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   var domainUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
   var entry = new DirectoryEntry("XXX");
   var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
   search.Filter = "(sameaccountname=)" + domainUserName + ")";
   // Check if the user is in domain or not
   var result = search.FindOne();
   if(result != null)
   {
      //Domain user, find the mapping user in db and login using the db user
      ...    
   }
}
```

Since the website should support both anonymous and windows authentication, I enabled both authentication method:

[image: windows_auth]

And also add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to `Login` ActionResult.

Per my understanding, the request authentication is performed in global.aspx, So I guess my authentication logic should have something to do with this:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
{
      ...
}
```

But it just seems that I could not put my authentication code in there. Because anyway, I need to use the db user to manage user roles, but in the global.aspx, the `UserManager` is not even there.

I have tried to add this piece of code into `Login` ActionResult, but there's a problem: when domain user logs out, it will constantly login as it can not tell if the user is actually logged out or just comes to the website.

So:

- Where is the right place to put those authentication code?
- How does the **Ldap** work in this scenario? Does **Ldap** meet the requirements? I could never get the *Ldap* work in my project.

Comment: Show your code for AD authentication in `Application_AuthenticateRequest()`.

Comment: @aaron, please see my updated question, many thanks!