# How to deploy ABP to IIS

Tags: deployment, aspnetboilerplate

I have a ABP template. It is a merged solution for Angular in Full .Net framework. I have already created a published package by right clicking on the Web.Host project and then Publish.
Here is a screenshot of my published folder:
[image]

I have also added a website in my local IIS and have pointed it to the wwwroot folder of my published folder as localhost:8081

I have modified the `appconfig.json` in the `wwwroot/assets` folder as:

```
{
   "remoteServiceBaseUrl": "http://localhost:8081",
   "appBaseUrl": "http://localhost:8081"
}
```

and have also changed `appsettings.json` to

```
"App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:8081/",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://localhost:8081/",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:8081,http://localhost:8081"
},
```

1. Do I need to add another Website in IIS for host? If Yes, where should I point it to? Again wwwroot? All the DLLs and appsettings.json are above the wwwroot. Should I bring them all inside the wwwroot?
2. When I navigate to the `localhost:8081` I get "Resource not found" prompt
3. I noticed that there is a `Web.Host.exe` file in the Published folder. When change all above settings to `localhost:5000` and execute it, it runs the host on `localhost:5000` and works fine for both `localhost:5000/swagger` and `localhost:5000/app/`
4. Do I need a website under IIS to execute the `Web.Host.exe`? If yes, how would I add such website? Where that port 5000 has been set for the `.exe` file?

If I change the website physical folder to the published folder (which holds the wwwroot folder) I get the following error (seems something is wrong with the web.config file):
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the *.NET Core Hosting Bundle*.

> 1. Install the *.NET Core Hosting Bundle* on the hosting system. ...
>      a. Navigate to the [.NET All Downloads page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all).
>      b. Select the latest non-preview .NET Core runtime from the list (**.NET Core > Runtime > .NET Core Runtime x.y.z**). ...
>      c. On the .NET Core runtime download page under **Windows**, select the **Hosting Bundle Installer** link to download the *.NET Core Hosting Bundle*.
>
>    ...
> 2. Restart the system or execute **net stop was /y** followed by **net start w3svc** from a command prompt. Restarting IIS picks up a change to the system PATH made by the installer.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Aaron, thank you very much for the comment. It resolves the issue! But I am a bit confused! Why would I need to install .Net Core when my target framework is Full .Net framework. I thought I would only need it if my project was Asp Core!!!??

Comment: Your project *is* ASP.NET Core. See [.NET Core vs ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136118/net-core-vs-asp-net-core).