# why there are .net framework option here

Tags: .net-core

I want to develope web application as Asp.net Core Web Application.

Although  I select Asp.Net Core Web Aplication  ,why there are .net framework option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ozeA.png)

Comment: Simply because you can [run ASP.NET Core on either .NET Core or .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework).

Comment: @KirkLarkin you should write that as an answer. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136118/net-core-vs-asp-net-core/44136528#44136528

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core vs ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136118/net-core-vs-asp-net-core)

Comment: @MartinUllrich I think your answer (and even the question itself) from the link you've provided cover this enough to answer the question here - I've voted to close as a dupe of that.