# .NET Core/ASP.NET Core/ASP.NET Core MVC practical use for web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking into my options with .NET (kind of an all eggs in one basket sort of thing) primarily because I like C# . But since the names have changed I am having a difficult time with the .NET Core, ASP.NET Core, and ASP.NET Core MVC titles.

I know my way around HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP/Laravel very well, and just as there is LAMP and MEAN, I would like to get a straight answer for once that just explains what stack MS recommends for development of web apps.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is .NET Core, and ASP.NET Core MVC is ASP.NET Core. What you want to compare is ASP.NET MVC (v5) and ASP.NET Core, and Microsoft recommends the latter for new developments.

Comment: .NET Core is the general framework on which you can build lots of different kinds of apps (e.g. console, forms, web app, background service, mobile app). ASP.NET Core is the basis for web applications, built on top of . NET Core. MVC is one flavour of ASP.NET. you can Google all of these terms and get explanations of what they are, if you need more detailed info

Comment: For .net core and Asp.net core, try to refer [.NET Core vs ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136118/net-core-vs-asp-net-core), and for asp.net core mvc, it is a specific template to build mvc project under asp.net core.