# Whats the difference between Asp.NetCore.App and .NETCore.App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

i want to understand the difference between the two .NET Runtimes Microsoft.AspNetCore.App abd Microsof.NETCore.App,

i run

```
dotnet --info
```

cmd command,

i see many runtimes, i want to know the difference between the two. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136118/net-core-vs-asp-net-core

Comment: You mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0?

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0) :
The ASP.NET Core shared framework (Microsoft.AspNetCore.App) contains assemblies that are developed and supported by Microsoft. Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is installed when the .NET Core 3.0 or later SDK is installed. The shared framework is the set of assemblies (.dll files) that are installed on the machine and includes a runtime component and a targeting pack