# What visual studio template can i use for a server that will communicate with devices and uses web pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services

I need an application that will communicate with other applications (android apps and arduino sensors, etc) throught json with visual studio IDE but this application should host a local web page too (to modify the system and deliver stadistics).

I do not have a lot of experience with visual studio or distributed systems. What template should i use for a project with this characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the "Asp.Net Core Web Application" template!

When you open Visual Studio, select "New Project" then in the search box write "Asp.Net Core Web Application like in the picture below:

[image]

Pick the one with the C# Tag!

That's it you have your template!

Rest Api is what you want, it uses json to communicate with other Apps, you can then have multiple Apps communicating with your Rest API, you can also use Swagger to create your rest API interface so you can easily see your endpoints documented there.

Good look with your Project!

Comment: Thank you very much!, i had doubs too about using that template (asp.net core web application) or "asp.net web application" but it looks that are almost the same but i believe the first one is the ideal one.

Comment: @LuisRococo: you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820947/whats-the-difference-between-asp-net-5-net-core-and-asp-net-core-5?answertab=votes#tab-top

The differences between Asp.Net, .Net Core and Asp.Net Core!

Core is the most recent technology!

Thank you for accepting my answer, i voted up your question and I would appreciate a loot  if you vote up my answer. Regards :)