# web api search with DateTime and Double variables in path

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am working on a web api and I need to be able to search a path with a `DateTime` and receive all books that contain that `Date`.

So for example  `/api/books/published/2012` returns all with 2012 in their date.
As well as `api/books/published/2012/8/15` returns all with 2012-08-15 in their's.

I have tried

```
 public ActionResult GetBooksSortedByDate()
    {
        if (!_bookList.Any())
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(_bookList);
    }
    [HttpGet("published/{published}")]
    public IActionResult GetBookByDate(DateTime published)
    {
        var book = FindBookByDate(published);
        if (book is null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(book);
    }
    //returnerar böcker innehållandes sökt datum
    private IEnumerable<Book> FindBookByDate(DateTime published)
    {
        return _bookList.Where(_bookList => _bookList.Publish_date.Equals(published));
    }
```

Using `/api/books/published/2012-8-15` in Postman gets me the book created then.

meanwhile `/api/books/published/2012` does not give me any objects. And I know this is because I have set `_booklist.Publish_date.Equals(published));` .

So what do I need to replace `.Equals` with to get something along the lines of a `.Contains(Value)`

**And regarding double**

I want to be able to do the following.

```
/api/books/price/30.0&35.0 returns all with price between '30.0' och '35.0'
```

Same situation here, I get results on `/api/books/price/33.0` but I do not know how to do a price between 30.0 and 35.0.

My code looks like this. I believe I need to send in 2 doubles here for it to check both of them?

```
  //Visar /price/value&value
    [HttpGet("price/{price}&{price}")]
    public IActionResult GetBooksByTwoPrices(double firstPrice, double secondPrice)
    {
        var book = FindBooksByTwoPrices(firstPrice,secondPrice);
        if (book is null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(book);
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<Book> FindBooksByTwoPrices(double firstPrice, double secondPrice)
    {
        var allBooksBetweenPrices = _bookList.Where(_bookList => _bookList.Price.Equals(firstPrice) && _bookList.Price.Equals(secondPrice);
        return allBooksBetweenPrices;
        //return _bookList.Where(_bookList => _bookList.Price.Equals(price));
    }
```

I know my `var allBooksBetweenPrices = ...` does not work as it can't be 2 value's at once but I guess this is somewhat the way to approach it?

Worth to note... My **Book.cs** only contains  `public double price { get; set; }` Do I need another one to check for the other price?

Comment: Reason why `2012-8-15` works as a `DateTime` and `2012` not is because model binder tries to parse the route parameter `string` to `DateTime` and `2012` is not a valid date time string. You can see for yourself using `DateTime.Parse()` method. Also, are route-based parameters a requirement? If not, then I suggest accepting the parameters from query, that would make your life much easier, you could have multiple parameters for example. Read more about [model binding in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources).

Comment: @Prolog I've been trying to understand the route-based parameters but it seems that I get them wrong every time. Can you show how it's supposed to look like on my code for example? Might be easier to understand with a smaller example.. As for the DateTime... Where do I do `DateTime.Parse()`?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET? Please specify framework version you are using. If you don't know, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29820947/8065832).

Comment: @Prolog I'm using ASP.NET 5. It was supposed to be ASP.NET 5.0 Core but I did not have that when creating a new project and I noticed it too late..

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, i'd suggest something like:

```
_bookList.Where(_bookList => _bookList.Publish_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").Contains(published));
```

For the second part, you could do something like:

```
var allBooksBetweenPrices = _bookList.Where(_bookList => (_bookList.Price >= firstPrice) && (_bookList.Price <= secondPrice));
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. On the first part I just get an argument `cannot convert from 'system.DateTime' to 'char' ` and I dont really understand what's expecting a char..? For the second part. How do I actually setup the method? `firstPrice & secondPrice` both have 0 in value, they dont recieve any values so to say. Is it because my `Book.cs` only contain 1 ` public double price { get; set; }` ?

Comment: its because i didnt realize you have already parsed the string to a DateTime at that point. `.Contains()` needs a string / char array not a DateTime. I read your thoughts and concluded that you are taking in strings to define the date. i think we should have different methods here, one to compare an exact date and another to do timespans like a whole year - if i didn't missunderstand you...

Comment: To clarify. `api/books/published/2012` returns all books from 2012 meanwhile `/api/books/published/2012/8/15` returns all books from 2012-08-15. It looks as if my `DateTime` variable sets to "2012-08-01" when I write `api/books/published/2012-08`. So could it be done so that `published/value` is a `string` and I return it as a `DateTime`? That way I could use `.Contains()` ?

Comment: you are still confusing a little: is it /2021/8/16 or 2015-8-15 now? you can't use contains like that when 2021 is converted to 2021-01-01

Comment: My bad. It want to be able to use produced/2015/8/15 as a path to reach A book that is created at that date. While at the same time be able to use produced/2015 as a path to reach ALL books that are created that year.

Comment: like i said, i'd just keep it simple and use two api calls for two different questions... one is "GetBooksByDate" the other one is "GetBookByTimespan" then we dodge the problems with different parameter types